# hacer mas largo select menu

Tags: html, bootstrap, select

Estoy implementando este form select de bootstrap, pero al quererlo hacer mas largo no me deja mas alla de los 500%

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>

<select class="form-select" size="3" aria-label="size 3 select example">
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```

e intendo con `style="width:500px"` y tambien desde css, pero no se alarga mas alla, alguna sugerencia de como poder?

css

```
.form-select{
width:500%;
}
```

agregando el link de bootstrap, sucede esto con el select, lo hace muy pequeño

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
gracias

Comment: Eso, sin agregar nada más (ni el style),  te deberia coger todo el ancho de su contenedor. Por lo tanto revisa más bien su contenedor y hazlo mas ancho.

Comment: Probé tu código y ocupa el **width al 100%**. Agrega el HTML y CSS para ver que puede estar pasando.

Comment: no tengo ningun content, esta dentro del body nada mas y los estilos los estoy agregando en el archivo por default site.css de c#

Comment: Te he agregado el bootstrap. Prueba tu propio código ahora y date cuenta que si que ocupa todo el ancho. Quizas es que tu no has puesto el bootstrap en tu sitio.

Answer (score 0):

creo que esto te vale

```css
.anchura{
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  width:500px;
   
   }
```

```html
<select class="form-select anchura" size="3" aria-label="size 3 select example" >
  <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```